# Double exponential problems?

Tags: algorithm, np-complete, np

Are there any significant problems in computer science that can only be solved in [double exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function) time ? And if they exist then to which class of problems do they belong ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function#Algorithmic_complexity):

In computational complexity theory, some algorithms take double-exponential time:

- Each decision procedure for Presburger arithmetic provably requires at least double-exponential time
- Computing a Gröbner basis over a field. In the worst case, a Gröbner basis may have a number of elements which is doubly exponential in the number of variables.
- Finding a complete set of associative-commutative unifiers
- Satisfying CTL+ (which is, in fact, 2-EXPTIME-complete)
- Quantifier elimination on real closed fields takes a doubly-exponential time (see Cylindrical algebraic decomposition).
- Calculating the complement of a regular expression